# I'm trying to use pip install to add numpy, but it says the file doesn't exist

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I've tried upgrading pip install (it was already done), poked around in various pip and wheel related python files, but all that happens when i run the following command into my command prompt (cmd.exe)

```
pip install pip install numpy-1.13.3+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

This is the error I have

> Requirement 'numpy-1.13.3+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist. numpy-1.13.3+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

My system is, as far as I know, a 64 bit windows system

Comment: just do `pip install numpy`

Comment: you're kidding me, right....? woow.

Comment: worked? @dood ..

Comment: I will tell you that the `pip install pip install` bit won't help. It's just `pip install`.

Comment: it did work, also, the pip install pip install thing wasn't really affecting much

Comment: you mean that part that still gave me the same output? yep.....

Answer (score 4):

just `pip install numpy` will take care of downloading and installing necessary module versions. You dont need to mention module version

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution, which was to install `numpy`

```
pip install numpy
```

Comment: this is not a clear answer. Please refrain using spoken word like `sooo`